# Mixins in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to create a trait in Scala:

```
trait First {
  override def greet() {
    super.greet
    println("First")
  }
}
```

but compiler says:

```
scala/scala_learning/traits_hierarchy.scala:3: error: value greet is not a member of java.lang.Object with ScalaObject
    super.greet
          ^
```

But I would like to extend with this trait some class which superclass has method greet... Is it possible in scala?

Answer (score 5):

While there are structural types in scala, I don't think you can do that for any type that has a greet method, but for a greet method in a specific trait or class.

Then if you want to have your routine change a routine not yet defined, calling it with super, it must be tagged `abstract overrid`e, not simply override.

That would be

```
trait Greeter { def greet }

trait First extends Greeter {
  abstract override def greet = {
    super.greet
    println("Hi, I'm first")
  }
}
```

Then you can have greet definition

```
class StandardGreeter(greeting: String) extends Greeter {
  def greet = println(greeting)
}
```

Note that First was defined without knowledge of StandardGreeter. You mix in new classes with

```
class FirstGreeter(greeting: String) extends StandardGreeter(greeting) with First
```

or create instances directly with

```
new StandardGreeter("whatever") with First
```

You may want to read [this article](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do this with structural self types:

```
trait Foobar {
    this: { def greet() } => // self type
    def go() = greet()
}
class Barbar extends Foobar { def greet() = { println("hello") }}
```

You are defining that Foobar can only extend a class which defines a method greet(). Using the REPL:

```
scala> trait Foobar { this: { def greet() } =>
     | def go() = greet()
     | }
defined class Foobar

scala> new Foobar()
<console>:9: error: class Foobar cannot be instantiated because it does not conform to its self-type Foobar with AnyRef{def greet(): Unit}
              new Foobar()
              ^

scala> class Barbar extends Foobar { def greet() = { println("hello") }}
defined class Barbar

scala> new Barbar().go
hello
```

You can then override the greet method in Foobar (but what use this is I don't know):

```
trait Foobar {
    this: { def greet() } => // self type
    override def greet() = { println("mygreet") }
    def go() = greet()
}
class Barbar extends Foobar
```

Comment: Ok, but do where does a mixin come in?

Comment: @didierd `FooBar` can be a `trait`.

Comment: @Daniel. Mayve a matter of understanding of the question. I thought the point was to have greet call super.greet + something else, which is usually an abstract override. Here we have a structural constraint on what you can mix in with, which is no mean feat, but can we do something akin to abstract override?

Comment: @didierd. You're right, I meant to use trait Foobar instead of class. you may be right about the OP. We'll wait and see what he says.