# using duck typing to create mixins in Scala, can i decorate existing methods in a class that has no 'knowledge' of the mixin trait?

Tags: scala, mixins, traits

I just discovered how one can use duck typing to create 
mixins in Scala that dynamically extend the behavior of 
a class that was created with no knowledge of the mixin.  I am able to do this by 
creating a mixin that adds a method that 'decorates' an existing method. This is 
illustrated below.

```
trait Foobar {
    this: {def origGreetingMethod()} => // this is 'duck typing' right?
    def decoratedGreetingMethod() = { 
        origGreetingMethod() ; println("done greeting") 
    }
}

class Tarbar { def origGreetingMethod() = { println("hello") }}
val y = new Tarbar() with Foobar
y.decoratedGreetingMethod    // when run from REPL prints "hello\ndone greeting"
```

Notice that the decorating method has a different name than the original. I was wondering :
is there  some way that I could actually override and extend the ORGINAL method (i.e., origGreetingMethod) of the 
class that is being decorated by the mixin method?

Here's the reason I would want to do this: (1) say I have method that takes a Tarbar instance... 
And (2) lets say that this method and the Tarbar class it references were developed in absence of 
my requirement that everytime after invoking origGreetingMethod on a Tarbar I need to do something 
else (collect metrics, cleanup.. whatever).

```
def doSomething(tarbar: Tarbar) { 
    tarbar. origGreetingMethod
    println("doing something useful...")
}
```

It would be very convenient if I could tweak Foobar so that it overrides the behavior in 
origGreetingMethod and doesnt require me to call decoratedGreetingMethod to get this 
new functionality.

I tried the abstract override approach mentioned in this post:
[Mixins in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866571/mixins-in-scala/7866714#7866714)

But I could not get it to work.   Any guidance most appreciated !
thanks

Comment: "Duct" typing?  Surely you mean duck typing.

Comment: Duct typing is when you wrap a type. If it doesn't stick, it becomes a leaky abstraction.

Comment: @jwvh    Should  have had my ducks in a row before I posted !     Thanks for the correction.. I eliminated the ducts, replaced w/ ducks.    and you will hear no more wise quacks from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started playing around with some code.  I'm wondering if this is what you had in mind:

```
scala> class Tarbar { def origGreetingMethod() = println("hello") }
defined class Tarbar

scala> trait Foobar extends Tarbar {
     | abstract override def origGreetingMethod() = {
     | super.origGreetingMethod()
     | println("extra") }}
defined trait Foobar

scala> val y = new Tarbar() with Foobar
y: Tarbar with Foobar = $anon$1@cbf6c1e

scala> y.origGreetingMethod()
hello
extra
```

I think @SillyFreak has offered this answer.  I just plugged it into your example code.

Comment: jwvh & @SillyFreak   thank you both for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The way this *would* be going is using `abstract override def`. [this page](http://www.lorrin.org/blog/2012/08/09/scalas-abstract-override-stackable-traits-and-object-hierarchy-linearization/) has a nice example, and here is a barebones example:

```
trait Trait {
  def foo(): Unit
}

trait A extends Trait {
  def foo(): Unit = println("A")
}

trait B extends Trait {
  abstract override def foo(): Unit = { println("B"); super.foo() }
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  (new Object with A).foo() //output: A
  (new Object with A with B).foo() // output: B A
  //those won't compile
  //(new Object with B).foo()
  //(new Object with B with A).foo()
}
```

Now on to duck typing: I wrote a trait like this:

```
trait C {
  self: { def foo(): Unit } =>
  abstract override def foo(): Unit = { println("B"); self.foo() }
}
```

Note that `super.foo()` doesn't work. Scala recognizes that `abstract override` is legal (and it wouldn't be without the self type), but the call to the delegate is via `self`. So far, so good, but that's where I stumbled:

```
(new Object with A with C).foo()
```

gives the following error message:

> overriding method `foo` in trait `A` of type `()Unit`; method `foo` in trait `C` of type `()Unit` cannot override a concrete member without a third member that's overridden by both (this rule is designed to prevent accidental overrides'')

I don't exactly get what's meant by "[unless there's] a third member that's overridden by both", but in the end it doesn't work. Whether it's a bug (because `abstract override` can't have these issues and it should work), a limitation of `abstract override`'s implementation, or a genuinely useful error (because `abstract override` is indeed dangerous here), I can't tell.

So, sorry I couldn't help you in the end. I'd continue with these follow up questions:

- Is there any way to use trait `C`, or will you always get that error?
- what harm can come from mixing in trait C?
- Is the error message a false positive of the Scala compiler, or necessary to prevent dangerous constructs?
- What does the compiler message mean exactly?

(If you're going to ask these questions, please leave a link, that would be interesting to me as well)

Comment: A third member, to overcome this issue, would be `trait D { override def foo() = super.foo() } extends A with B`